# Parsing JSON returns EOF

Tags: json, go

I seem to overlook something. Trying to decode some json into a struct. I have checked that the json response is valid. Typing the URL into the browser returns that valid json. For some reason, though I still get an error `EOF`. I have also used the [json-to-go](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) to verify my structs. Error is thrown at the `json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&servResp)`part

Code:

```
type OnvistaServiceCallCandleData struct {
    Status   string      `json:"status"`
    ErrorMsg string      `json:"errorMsg"`
    Result   []AssetData `json:"result"`
}

type AssetData struct {
    Date   string `json:"date"`
    Open   string `json:"open"`
    High   string `json:"high"`
    Low    string `json:"low"`
    Close  string `json:"close"`
    Volume string `json:"volume"`
}

func ServiceOnvistaAssetData(data OnvistaInstrument) ([]models.InstrumentData, error) {
    url := "some-valid-url"


    myClient := http.Client{
        Timeout: time.Second * 10,
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(url)

    response, getErr := myClient.Do(req)
    if getErr != nil {
        log.Fatal(getErr)
    }

    if response.Body != nil {
        defer response.Body.Close()
    } else {
        fmt.Println("response.Body nil")
    }
   
    servResp := OnvistaServiceCallCandleData{}
    jsonErr := json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&servResp)
    if jsonErr != nil {
        log.Fatal(jsonErr)
    }

    if servResp.Status == "error" {
        return []models.InstrumentData{}, errors.New(servResp.ErrorMsg)
    }

    currentLocation := time.Now().Location()
    toReturn := []models.InstrumentData{}
    for i := range servResp.Result {

        s := strings.Split(servResp.Result[i].Date, ".")
        dataTimestamp := time.Date(parseInt(s[2]), time.Month(parseInt(s[1])), parseInt(s[0]), 0, 0, 0, 0, currentLocation)

        newToReturn := models.InstrumentData{
            InstrumentID:  data.InstrumentID,
            DataTimestamp: dataTimestamp,
            Open:          parseFloat(servResp.Result[i].Open),
            Close:         parseFloat(servResp.Result[i].Close),
            High:          parseFloat(servResp.Result[i].High),
            Low:           parseFloat(servResp.Result[i].Low),
            Volume:        parseFloat(servResp.Result[i].Volume),
        }
        toReturn = append(toReturn, newToReturn)

    }

    return toReturn, nil
}
```

Comment: Do you also get valid json if you make a request with curl to `"some-valid-url"`?

Comment: The error `EOF` indicates that the response body is empty.  Print `response.Status` before decoding.  The value may give a hint about what's wrong.

Comment: You could use `ioutil.ReadAll` to get all data returned from the server in the body, and print that out to see if you get correct JSON in the program (or just plain ol' `io.Copy` to `os.Stdout`...)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out what was wrong. In the URL I had some whitespace. So `url.QueryEscape()` each parameter did the trick.